# Stack images one or merging base64 images

Tags: javascript, php, base64, heatmap

I have a collection of heatmap images where i need to place above of the image, the only issue is that i cant overlap a collection of images each other with css,  but the perfect result would be to merge a collection of bsae64 images to one.

Example my code:

```
@foreach(...)
 <img style="position: absolute;z-index: {{99999 + $key}};" alt="Embedded Image" src="{{$heat->imageBase64}}" />

@endforeach
```

Comment: Why can't you use css using position:absolute and z-index?  What is the behavior that's happening?

Comment: Ok... Good luck with that? Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: @nixkuroi i already tried that, basically i tried increment in the foreach loop the z-index and also putting the position absolute, but isnt working.

Comment: Can you post the rendered code?  That would make it easier to debug.  It looks like you have $heat  or handlebars doing the work, so I'm interested to see what's emitted.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `opacity` rather than `z-index`.

```
<img style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACPSURBVFhH7dixDYAgFABRdEkbxqNxPRdQCzoT9b7ND95rJLHwAgai076VhOZ+TcYswizCLMIswizCLMIswizCLMIswiwiadanz9e2tD66qGvto5D4bN00ne7vPorMFnpkbNpGeeXp6sRW0w2CMIsYJYvuQ//et07vJyB8MiY9qv0BTphFmEWYRZhFpMwq5QAAcB8VENYVogAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
<img style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:70px" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACaSURBVFhH7dfBDUAwGEDhsoJ1TGYAg5jFMC524NCLA/X+OjTy3kUTh/9LhUaXli21V5+vjSWLJIvUKOuDD8Q+jXl1bZjXvOLV7tad6ezhVrEqVnFwWBZnvRwZk/kmkmSRZJF+x3p5tsSOoKrdKo4MH4u1D/FhcNh05i8GSRZJFkkWSRZJFkkWSRZJFkkWSRZJFkkWSRapSVZKBz/RGgBpmbaeAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">

<img style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:130px;opacity:0.5" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACPSURBVFhH7dixDYAgFABRdEkbxqNxPRdQCzoT9b7ND95rJLHwAgai076VhOZ+TcYswizCLMIswizCLMIswizCLMIswiwiadanz9e2tD66qGvto5D4bN00ne7vPorMFnpkbNpGeeXp6sRW0w2CMIsYJYvuQ//et07vJyB8MiY9qv0BTphFmEWYRZhFpMwq5QAAcB8VENYVogAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
<img style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:130px;opacity:0.5" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACaSURBVFhH7dfBDUAwGEDhsoJ1TGYAg5jFMC524NCLA/X+OjTy3kUTh/9LhUaXli21V5+vjSWLJIvUKOuDD8Q+jXl1bZjXvOLV7tad6ezhVrEqVnFwWBZnvRwZk/kmkmSRZJF+x3p5tsSOoKrdKo4MH4u1D/FhcNh05i8GSRZJFkkWSRZJFkkWSRZJFkkWSRZJFkkWSRapSVZKBz/RGgBpmbaeAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
```

Comment: Its not working, i have like a collection of images (8), and i already tried these 2 examples and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my solution but using background in css, above i leave my solution, basically.

background:

```
   url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
   url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
   url(Paper-4.png);                      /* On bottom, like z-index: 1; */
```